# How to adjust background image of a div?

Tags: background-image, css

I can't adjust background img of a div so it is filled by the image, regardless of div's and img's size. If the image is smaller then it should be streched and vice versa. The whole image should be visible, regardless of deformation and loss of quality.

I tried all this combinations and permutations, and many more. Simply - doesn't work.

```
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top center;
 background-size: auto;
 background-size: cover;
 background-size: contain;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

I use Firefox 22, css is valid css3, according to W3C validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for CSS3 only

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

UPD: For old IE you can use filters:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='imgpath', sizingMethod='scale')";  /* IE8 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='imgpath', sizingMethod='scale'); /* pre IE8 */
```

Comment: YD1m, I treid - doesn't work. In fact, how can know is my css  - css3 or not ? Old IE - are not important.

Comment: You can check supporting of `background-size` option [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Comment: YD1m, I just validated mu css on W3C - it's ok - it is valid css3. Also I use Firefox 22 - should be ok.

Comment: Just checked in FF 22 and Chrome 28 and [this fiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCL8/).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the same height and width for the image which you have given for the div.

```
var currentHeight = $('.element_class').height();
var currentWidth = $('.element_class').width(); 
$('.yourimage').height()=currentHeight;
$('.yourimage').height()=currentWidth;
```

Comment: Arun, in that case it works, but the div changes it's size dynamically. That's the reason I want do adjust its background.

Comment: get the dynamic divs                                              var currentHeight = $('.element_class').height();
 
// Get width of image inside a div
var currentWidth = $('.div_class img').width();  from jquery and set these values back to the img tag...got?if not i will update my code

Comment: Arun, thanks lot, but - must I use jquery fot this task ? CSS should do this, I believe.